# org.everit.json.schema.SchemaException: #: could not determine version

Tags: java, validation, jsonschema

A SchemaException gets thrown saying the version could not be determined as the title says. The schema version is clearly in the schema. This is all before data validation. Any ideas why this error gets thrown?

My schema is as follows:

```js
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
  "$defs": {},
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "randomString": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
And Java code:
```

```js
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                String schemaPath = new File("").getAbsolutePath() + schema.json;
                Object schemaObj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(schemaPath));
                org.json.simple.JSONObject schemaJson = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) schemaObj;
                JSONObject rawSchema = new JSONObject(schemaJson.toString());
                //This is where the SchemaException gets thrown, the line after this comment
                Schema schema = SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema);
                //schema.validate(json);
```

Comment: Maybe your implementation doesn't support that version yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library doesn't support draft 2020-12 and 2019-09.

You will have to use draft 7 for now (or use an other library).

Edit: the correct meta-schema URL for draft 7 is `"$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema"`

Comment: will your library support 2019 and 2020 in the future?

Comment: Probably at some point, as the part of a rewrite.

Comment: Any updates on supporting draft/2020-12 @erosb?

Comment: @ledex the currently active project is https://github.com/erosb/json-sKema/